# Adding rows of zeros in pandas

Tags: pandas

In my data, I got 2 columns. `row_id`, `meter_reading`.

```
row_id      meter_reading
1                 20
2                 30
3                 40
4                 50
5                 60
```

I want to add 10000 rows of zeros below the given table. so, after 5 and 60 it will go like this-

```
0                  0
0                  0
0                  0
0                  0
....................
....................
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to @santiagoNublado's answer, but use df.columns instead when initializing d (not enough rep to comment yet or I would have):

```
d = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(10000), columns=df.columns)
df = pd.concat([df,d])
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(10000), columns=['row_id','meter_reading'])
df = pd.concat([df, d])
```

Comment: @Rohan If you agree, please consider [accepting answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)